# c# to get oauth2 token but get error (Remote server returns 400 Bad Request)

Tags: c#, json, api, oauth

I am trying to use this C# to get oauth token from a website. But the below codes return '404 Bad Request' error. Is there anything wrong in my code? The website engineer says there should be a JSON file returned to show error details. How do I get that JSON file? What I can see is just 1 line error message in VS2012.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://xxxx.com/api/oauth/token");
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
           

            //write the data to post request
            String postData = "client_id=abc&client_secret=xxx&grant_type=client_credentials";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(postData);
            if (buffer != null)
            {
                webRequest.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
                webRequest.GetRequestStream().Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string strResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

I used Postman to send a request and I can get the token in its response. How should I modify my C# codes to get the token?
[image]

Comment: Lets move step by step. First thing, which I suggest you to do is verify whether your request actually valid. To answer on this question you can use Postman (or any other similar tool) to send the similar request which your app make, and see the result from the API, I assume with response body in json format.

Comment: Also just by looking a bit into your code, I do not see place where you actually attaching credentials (like username, password etc) to your request. I do assume that you need some creds in order to get access token.

Comment: Also I am pretty sure you can try to debug the above code, putting a breakpoint right after `HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();` and check what exactly your `response` variable have.

Comment: @Omelian Levkovych The website's help asks me to use client_ID & client_secret as credential. And what is Postman, is it a software?

Comment: Yes, it is a free software for API testing and developing purposes, a really cool thing in my day to day life. Here is a link [Postman](https://www.postman.com/)

Comment: I tried its web version. I send a POST request and then Postman shows 'The request has been blocked because of the CORS policy' and asks me to use desktop agent. I think I will have to install it on my PC to use it

Comment: @Omelian Levkovych I can use Postman to send JSON in request body and get the token. That means the web API is working. So how to change my C# codes above to get the token?

Comment: Try to debug your code and see what exactly you get in the response. So you will see whether your request is valid, if yes. It is possible that you should deserialize json to C# type.

Answer (score 0):

**Can you try like this**

```
public (string, string, string, string) GetOAuth(string CliendId, string ClientSecret, string OAuthURl)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var creds = $"client_id={CliendId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}&grant_type=client_credentials";

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
        var content = new StringContent(creds, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var response = httpClient.PostAsync(OAuthURl, content).Result;
        var jsonContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        var tokenObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonContent);
        
        var access_token = tokenObj?.access_token;
        var token_type = tokenObj?.token_type;
        var expires_in = tokenObj?.expires_in;
        var scope = tokenObj?.scope;

        return (access_token, token_type, expires_in, scope);
    }
}

private void HowTOUse()
{
    string access_token, token_type, expires_in, scope;
    (access_token, token_type, expires_in, scope) = GetOAuth("client_id", "client_secret", "oauthurl");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Try using like the below code hope this code will solve the problem

   private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://xxxx.com/api/oauth/token");
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
       

        //write the data to post request
        String postData = 
        "client_id=abc&client_secret=xxx&grant_type=client_credentials";
          //byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(postData);

         //add these lines

        byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        
        if (buffer != null)
        {
            webRequest.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
            webRequest.GetRequestStream().Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
     try
     { 
        using (HttpWebResponse response = 
           (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
               using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                    string strResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();

              TokenModel  dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenModel> 
                (strResponse);
                    token = dt.accessToken;
                //Assign json Token values from strResponse to model tok_val
                    tok_val.accessToken = dt.accessToken;
                    tok_val.expires_in = dt.expires_in;
                    tok_val.RefreshToken = dt.RefreshToken;
                    tok_val.tokenType = dt.tokenType;
               }
           }
      }


       catch (WebException wex)
        {

            error = "Request Issue: " + wex.Message;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = "Issue: " + ex.Message;
        }
```